# How do you translate “talk shit”?

Tags: traduction

I’ve seen a few ways (casser quelqu’un, dire des saloperies sur quelqu’un) but what are the more common ones?

It means to say bad things about someone when they’re not around.

Ex. “He was talking shit about me but I had to hear it from someone else.”

Comment: “Best” isn't an objective criterion. If you want to know what are common ways to express something, please disambiguate by providing contexts and by explaining what is to be conveyed by this phrase.

Comment: i edited it! thank you for the input!

Answer (score 12):

Using "talk shit" [Urban Dictionary definitions](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=talk%20shit)

1.) To say something insulting or rude about another person, either to their face or behind their back.

> - *Dire/raconter des [saloperies](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/saloperie) sur quelqu'un*
> - *[Casser](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/casser) quelqu'un*
> - *[Baver](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/baver) (sur/dessus)*
> - *[Tailler un costard](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tailler_un_costard) à quelqu'un*  (mild)
> - *[Clabauder](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clabauder)* (literary, outdated)
> - *Mal parler*
> - *Balancer* (disclose personal things, betray)

2.) To make a statement that is exaggerated or flat-out untrue

> - *Raconter des conneries*

3.) To say something negative behind someone's back that you wouldn't say to their face.

> - *Dire/raconter/balancer des [saloperies](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/saloperie) dans le dos de quelqu'un*
> - *[Casser du sucre sur le dos](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/casser_du_sucre_sur_le_dos_de) de quelqu'un* (outdated)
> - *Être une [langue de vipère](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/langue_de_vip%C3%A8re)*
> - *Être une [langue de pute](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/langue_de_pute)* (very offensive/vulgar)

Your sentence "He was talking shit about me but I had to hear it from someone else" might then be translated with:

> *Il racontait un tas de conneries sur moi mais il a fallu que je l'apprenne de quelqu'un d'autre.*

Comment: Il y a "*mal parlé*" aussi avec le sens de "dire des choses méchantes, négatives sur qqn", donc la définition 1). Ex: "*Elle était à la soirée et elle a trop mal parlé sur toi*" ou "*Parle pas mal de ma mère !!*" C'est celui que je connais qui est le plus proche de *talk shit* (en "language des jeunes" en tout cas)

Comment: To stress the idea of spreading bad things, you can also use the verb *balancer*: *il a balancé des saloperies sur mon dos*.

Answer (score 3):

I think *Dire de la merde*, *Dire des conneries* is more apropriate.
It doesn't necessarily relate to someone.

Comment: "talking shit" is saving bad thing about amoething or someone. For something you're right. For someone it can be also "insulter", "dire du mal"...

Comment: If you want to talk about someone, you say "Why do you talk shit *about me* ?", for example. *Talk shit* alone doesn't necessarily relate to someone, i think :).

Comment: @shaax Talking shit is always about someone, it's not used alone. Maybe you're thinking of "shooting the shit", which is an idiom for small talk.

Comment: @Barmar That's not what [Urban](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=talk%20shit) or [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talk_shit#English) say.